# Google Analytics Video Tracking Issue with JWPlayer 6

Tags: google-analytics, jwplayer, issue-tracking

I'm new to all this and am just not getting how to track a video that can be played on my site. 
I just installed my GA code to my page, so I'm going to assume that I'm using the new Asynchronous  tracking. the issue is am not able to track this video in GA panel.
Thanks

My code looks like this .

```
   <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jwplayer.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jwplayer.html5.js'></script>
```

```
   (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
       i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
           (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
       }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
  m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
   })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
   ga('create', 'UA-40700489-1', 'epcint.com');
   ga('send', 'pageview');
```

---

```
 <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key = "myplayerkey=";</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
            file: 'video.mp4',
            width: "100%",
            height: "480",
            autostart: true,
            ga: {


            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="mediaplayer">
 </div>
```

Any help will be highly appriciate 
Thanks

> Thanks for your feedback i have updated and Debug the code in GA
>   debugger i got the error whats this means ?
>
> > Initializing Google Analytics. analytics_debug.js:9 Registered new
> >     plugin: ga(provide, "linker", Function) analytics_debug.js:9
> >     Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "displayfeatures", Function)
> >     analytics_debug.js:9 Running command: ga(create, UA-40700489-2,
> >     infopav.com) analytics_debug.js:9 Creating new tracker: t0
> >     analytics_debug.js:9 Running command: ga(send, pageview)
> >     analytics_debug.js:9
> >
> > Sent beacon:
> >     v=1&_v=j16d&a=686083534&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.www.infopave.com%2FPage%2FIndex%2FHOW_TO_ACCESS_LTPP_DATA&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8…30201944&_u=MCCC~&cid=2101349279.1393503811&tid=UA-40700489-2&z=1727898794
>
> analytics_debug.js:9 adSenseId        (&a)   686083534
>   analytics_debug.js:9 apiVersion       (&v)   1 analytics_debug.js:9
>   clientId         (&cid) 2101349279.1393503811 analytics_debug.js:9
>   encoding         (&de)  UTF-8 analytics_debug.js:9 flashVersion
>   (&fl)  12.0 r0 analytics_debug.js:9 hitType          (&t)   pageview
>   analytics_debug.js:9 javaEnabled      (&je)  1 analytics_debug.js:9
>   language         (&ul)  en-us analytics_debug.js:9 location
>   (&dl)  http://dev.www.infopave.com/Page/Index/HOW_TO_ACCESS_LTPP_DATA
>   analytics_debug.js:9 screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit
>   analytics_debug.js:9 screenResolution (&sr)  1680x1050
>   analytics_debug.js:9 title            (&dt)  LTPP InfoPave - How to
>   Access LTPP Data? analytics_debug.js:9 trackingId       (&tid)
>   UA-40700489-2 analytics_debug.js:9 viewportSize     (&vp)  1665x429
>   analytics_debug.js:9
>
> ```
> There was an error while handling a listener: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null function
> ```
>
> (){if("array"==a.typeOf(m.playlist)&&2>m.playlist.length&&(0==m.playlist.length||
>       !m.playlist[0].sources||0==m.playlist[0].sources.length))g();else if(s.getStatus()==a.loaderstatus.COMPLETE){for(var
>   e=0;em.modes[e].type;if(r.supportsConfig())return
>   r.addEventListener(l.ERROR,d),r.embed(),c(b,f.events),b}m.fallback?(a.log("No
>   suitable players found and fallback enabled"),new
>   j.download(n,m,g)):(a.log("No suitable players found and fallback
>   disabled"),n.parentNode.replaceChild(h,
>       n))}} jwplayer.js:3
>
> event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard
>   event.preventDefault() instead. jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2 9 Could not add
>   internal listener jwplayer.js:3 There was an error calling back an
>   event handler

Updated Code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
            file: 'rtmp://s1nu7pjztotbeg.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:Help/How_To/GettingStarted_V2-Sm_x264.mp4',
            width: "100%",
            height: "480",
            autostart: true,
            events: {
                onComplete: function (evt) {

                },

                onReady: function (event) {

                    ga('send', 'event', 'Video Played', 'action', { 'page': 'http://dev.www.infopave.com/Page/Index/HOW_TO_ACCESS_LTPP_DATA' });

                },
                onPlay: function (evt) {

                },
                onVolume: function (evt) {
                    alert("the new volume is: " + evt.volume);
                }


            },


            ga: {

            }


        });

    });
```

> i want to send this when some one click the play button ,i want to send this code only

```
               ga('send', 'event', 'Video Played', 'action', { 'page': 'http://dev.www.infopave.com/Page/Index/HOW_TO_ACCESS_LTPP_DATA' });
```

How i can get that button click in jquery thanks for your help...

> Thanks any help will be highly appriciated

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you look into [Event-tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events).  You can add a tag in the onclick so that when a user clicks to view your video you will log an event that you can find in your google Analytics under `Behavior -> events`

I haven't tested this but you should be able to do something like:

```
<div id="mediaplayer" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'click', 'videoname');">
</div>
```

Note: Events will first show up in the standard report after 24 hours.  You can also see them in the real-time reports.

Comment: Thanks DaImTo for your help. i updated the about code for hyperlink button click but how i can do this when some one click the play button or pause button etc <a href="#PurchasePanelLink" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {'page': '/my-new-page'});">View Tracking Details</a>

Answer (score 1):

and finally i got success to solve my problem !

```
 <div id="mediaplayer">
</div>
<ul>
    <li>State: <span id="stateText">IDLE</span></li>
    <li>time: <span id="elapsedText">0</span></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">        jwplayer.key = "mykeyeasdfasdf2132131=";</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
        file: 'rtmp://s1nu7pjztotbeg.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:Help/How_To/GettingStarted_V2-Sm_x264.mp4',
        width: 465,
        height: 300,
        autostart: true,
        events: {
            onComplete: function (event) {


                var elapsedTime = jwplayer("mediaplayer").getPosition();
                var timedurationvalue = ((elapsedTime / 60).toFixed(2));
                updateValues();
                //ga('send', 'event', 'Video Completes', 'ULR of video or Title', 'Page URL', timedurationvalue);
            },
            onReady: function (event) {
                var elapsedTime = jwplayer("mediaplayer").getPosition();
                var timedurationvalue = ((elapsedTime / 60).toFixed(2));
                updateValues();
                //  ga('send', 'event', 'Video Plays', 'ULR of video or Title', 'Page URL', timedurationvalue);
            },
            onPlay: function (event) {
                var elapsedTime = jwplayer("mediaplayer").getPosition();
                var timedurationvalue = ((elapsedTime / 60).toFixed(2));
                //  ga('send', 'event', 'Video Plays', 'ULR of video or Title', 'Page URL', timedurationvalue);

                //                    ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', value);
            },
            onVolume: function (event) {
                updateValues();
                alert("onvolume called!");
            },
            onPause: function (event) {


                var elapsedTime = jwplayer("mediaplayer").getPosition();
                var timedurationvalue = ((elapsedTime / 60).toFixed(2));
                //  ga('send', 'event', 'Video Paused', 'ULR of video or Title', 'Page URL', timedurationvalue);

                alert("onpause called!");
            }
        }
    });
    function setText(id, messageText) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = messageText;
    }

            function updateValues() {
                var state = jwplayer("mediaplayer").getState();
                var elapsed = jwplayer("mediaplayer").getPosition();
                setText("stateText", state);
                setText("elapsedText", (elapsed / 60).toFixed(2));
            }
</script>
```

Comment: In the comments for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170231/how-to-get-seconds-played-and-percentage-played-events-from-jw-player-6-in-g JWPlayer staff say that the seconds played stats are unreliable when using their default implementation. Have you found your custom solution to have reliable stats for time played? They say the problem is related to HTML5 player.

Answer (score 0):

JW Player only supports ga.js for the time being. The new universal analytics does not work yet. That is why.

Comment: Thanks i updated the abou code for hyperlink button click but how i can do this when some one click the play button or pause button etc <a href="#PurchasePanelLink" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {'page': '/my-new-page'});">View Tracking Details</a>

Comment: I am not sure, the code that I am talking about is only for the JW Player.

Comment: Ethan Thanks i have updated my code you can see it in above its working fine when a video run at page load ie am calling it in document.ready its working fine can you help me how i can do this when some click the play button , pause button i want to track at that time please have a look my code i want to get jquery play button click of that palyer.

Comment: Well this is because on page load the call to ga: {}, is available.